# Flajolet Martin Algorithm Implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, hash, flajolet-martin

I am trying to implement Flajolet Martin algorithm. I have a dataset with over 6000 records but the output of the following code is 4096. Please help me in understanding the mistake being made by me.

```
import xxhash

import math

def return_trailing_zeroes(s):

s = str(s)  

  rev = s[::-1] 

  count = 0

  for i in rev:

    if i is '0':

     count = count + 1

   else:

    break       

  return count

def gethash(line):

  num=abs(xxhash.xxh32(line).intdigest())

  return num

fp=open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Data.txt","r")

h_max=0

for line in fp:

  hash_value_1 = gethash(line)

  binary_1 = format(hash_value_1, '032b')       

  t1 = return_trailing_zeroes(binary_1)

  if t1>h_max:

    h_max=t1

fp.close()

print(2**h_max)
```

I tried this implementation of HyperLogLog algorithm and the output of the following code is 2560.

> def return_trailing_zeroes(s):    s = str(s)      rev = s[::-1]       count = 0
> for i in rev:       if i is '0':            count = count + 1       else:           break
> return count
>
> h1_m=0
>
> h2_m=0
>
> h3_m=0
>
> h4_m=0
>
> fp=open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Data.txt","r")
>
> for line in fp:
>
> hash_value_1 = abs(xxhash.xxh32(line).intdigest())
>
> hash_value_2 = abs(hash32(line))
>
> hash_value_3 = abs(jhashcode.hashcode(line))
>
> hash_value_4 = abs(mmh3.hash(line))
>
> binary_1 = format(hash_value_1, '032b')
>
> binary_2 = format(hash_value_2, '032b')
>
> binary_3 = format(hash_value_3, '032b')
>
> binary_4 = format(hash_value_4, '032b')
>
> t1 = return_trailing_zeroes(binary_1)
>
> t2 = return_trailing_zeroes(binary_2)
>
> t3 = return_trailing_zeroes(binary_3)
>
> t4 = return_trailing_zeroes(binary_4)
>
> if t1>h1_m:    h1_m=t1
>
> if t2>h2_m:    h2_m=t2
>
> if t3>h3_m:    h3_m=t3
>
> if t4>h4_m:    h4_m=t4
>
> fp.close()
>
> avg_hash12 = (2**(h1_m) + 2**(h2_m))/ float(2)
>
> avg_hash34 = (2**(h3_m) + 2**(h4_m))/ float(2)
>
> distinct_elements = math.ceil(statistics.median([avg_hash12,
> avg_hash34]))
>
> print(distinct_elements)

Comment: A single estimate is pretty bad by itself, so you need to repeat the process many times and take a harmonic mean or something (don't remember the details offhand).

Comment: I tried implementing that but I am still not getting the correct answer. I have added the code for that in my question @DavidEisenstat